# Magento 2.4.2 - reporting_system_updates table contain large data

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.4.2, optimization

I want to optimize the reporting_system_updates table in my database it is already over 5GB of data.
Can I safely truncate/delete this table?
If so then anything will happen with my Magento setup?

Also, I want to disable the logs of the reporting_system_updates table, where can I find the logs of this module and disable them?
Is there any solution for the optimization of this table data?

Answer (score 0):

The `reporting_system_updates` and `reporting_users` are tables for the newrelic reporting functionality, you can truncate the data if you don't use the newrelic in your project or you don't need this data.

The data will be saved there if the `newrelicreporting/general/enable` config is enabled

So basically you have few ways:

- disable `newrelicreporting/general/enable` config
- disable observers that save that information to your database: `Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Observer...`
- write custom module that will delete old data from that table every day, e.g. older than 1 week